# paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, paramiko

This is my first post so hopefully it is appropriate and not redundant.

I have an application I have deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a Flask Dash API. I have a snippet with the API that needs to connect to my Raspberry Pi remotely (SSH) and parse out some file.

- This code snippet works flawlessly on my local machine
- I can easily putty/ssh into my RPi on port 22
- On my 1st router I have port 22 opened tcp/udp
- On my 2nd router I have a NAT Forwarding Virtual Server rule for port 22 to direct to my RPI's static IP address

```
    import paramiko
    import json
        
    client =  paramiko.client.SSHClient()
    hostname='example'
    port=22
    username='pi'
    password='masked'
        
        
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    print('loaded client')
    client.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
        
    sftp_client = client.open_sftp()
        
    localFilePath='./some_file.json'
    sftp_client.get('/home/pi/some_file.json', localFilePath)
            
    sftp_client.close()
```

I get error paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on

I am assuming this is some sort of networking access issue on the AWS side or possibly my router. I can easily connect to my RPi from outside of my own network also. I tried to add some inbound/outbound rules on my EC2 load balancer, but even opening it up completely did not resolve the issue. I have raked through the webs and cannot find many answers, so I am hoping someone has suggestions which can also be beneficial to others.

Thanks!
[EC2 Instance SG Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA6VG.jpg)

Comment: Can you ssh into your EB instance, and then try to ssh from it to your RPi?

Comment: I have not tried that, but what I want to accomplish is basically having my EB website, SSH into my RPI, and basically output some value on the website. I even secured the EB site (SSL/HTTPS), and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: If you EB instances don't have connection to your RPi, then connections will fail. Thus if you ssh into the EB instance and try to connect manually to RPI is a good way to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: I am trying now, having issues SSHing into eb. I setup key, allowed port 22 to instance, still gives error connecting.

Comment: Do you get specific error message when you attempt to ssh, or timeout? Did you try web browser client ssh?

Comment: I am using EB CLI and receive:
```
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
INFO: Running ssh -i C:\Users\vahan\.ssh\aws-eb2 ec2-user@xx.xx.xx.xx
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.x port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while running: ssh.
```

Comment: Have to go to EC2 console, and inspect security group of your eb instance.

Comment: I went into the instance, found security group, and opened port 22 for any address and also tried my IP. Both give me same error. I tried Google Secure Shell, and it gave me connection refused error. I have no idea what is happening at this point. I feel like there is some setting or something I missed.

Comment: Can you post your instance inbound SG. I also asusme the instance has public IP?

Comment: I added an image to original post. I had my ip address for 22. I also tried all traffic for 22 inbound and no dice.

Comment: ssh is restricted to specific IP. Are you sure you are connecting from that IP to the instance?

Comment: Yes I am using the newly generated IP address (public) of the instance. I just times out. I used this article to trouble shoot the time out issue (ACL, VPC, SGs, etc.) I am at a lost. It just seems like it cannot even ping the EC2 at all.

Comment: Can you just set 0.0.0.0/0 instead of your IP, just to double check.

Comment: I terminated environment, and created again, allowed port 22 from any IP to the EC2 instance, still cannot SSH into the ip of the Ec2 instance. Keeps timing out. when I do eb ssh or try to connect from any SSH client. Very strange that this happens. I am unsure what more I can do.

Comment: Ok finally was able to SSH. Seems like it does not work with a client, but does work with AWS session manager. I had to attach an IAM role with full admin access to EC2 (on that role). When i try to ssh into my RPi from EC2, says connection refused, even though I have port 22 open on my router.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Glad it works now. If you want you can answer your own questions, or if  I can also make it based on your comments?

Comment: Well it is still not resolved because I cannot connect to my RPi using EC2 command line. That is the whole issue I want to resolve.I am able to SSH into my RPi with any other PC just fine. I have port 22 open on my router.

Comment: Ah ok. So not this is your RPi issue. Do you have any home/work firewalls blocking such connections? Maybe need to go through some proxy?

Comment: I disabled all firewalls from both of my routers, and still says connection refused. I guess the good sign is that the EC2 instance is attempting to connect, its just being blocked from something. I have an xfinity router and then a secondary one jumped off that which my RPi connects to. I can connect to my RPi from remote networks just fine; outside my IP.

Comment: What is interesting that I started a linux instance using Lightsail, I was able to ssh into my RPi once, and then every attempt afterwards, gives me connection refused. Somehow it connects and allows me to control the RPi from AWS Lightsail, and then every attempt afterwards does not work. I even kill the SSHD on RPI side and does not work.

Comment: wow incredibly annoying, so Xfinity has a firewall enabled that is outside the router settings. Had to log into xFi mobile app, go to more, and myservices. Disable firewall. No whitelisting option which is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Xfinity has a firewall enabled that is outside the router settings. Had to log into xFi mobile app, go to More, and My Services. Disable firewall. No whitelisting option which is terrible.